# degree of a line bundle on a curve in a surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $L$ be a base point free line bundle on a smooth irreducible projective curve $C$ of genus $g$. Then is there any way to calculate $deg(\mathcal O_C(m) \otimes L^*) $ in terms of genus of the curve and degree of the line bundle $L$?

In this context if the curve $C \in |nH|$ is a smooth irreducible projective curve for $H$ be an hyperplane class of a surface $X$ ,then can we say that $deg(i_*O_C(m) \otimes i_* L^*) = deg (\mathcal O_C(m) \otimes L^*) $ ?

Any help from anyone is welcome

Comment: As it appears $deg(\mathcal O_C(m) \otimes L^*) = deg(\mathcal O_C(m) )+ deg(L^*)$.Now $deg(L^*) =-deg(L)$ but what about deg$\mathcal O_C(m)$ ?How it's related to the genus of the curve?

Comment: The degree of the curve is precisely given by $d=deg(C) =deg(\mathcal O_C(1))$, so the first term is $md$.